# How to fix"DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'num_classes'"?

Tags: dataframe, keras, tf.keras

I'm loading the training images with tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator class. I choose to use flow_from_dataframe function. However, when I try to try to create a layer with num_classes, I got the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'num_classes'

```
    datagen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

image_data=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df[:1700],
directory='/tf/notebooks/2222/Face Images',
x_col="Filename",
y_col="Race",
batch_size=32,
#seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(224,224))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.Dense(image_data.num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an other method to get the number of classes in case of `flow_from_dataframe`:

For example:
`len(train_generator.class_indices)`

So your code should look like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.Dense(len(image_data.class_indices), activation='softmax')
])
```